# Bootstrap button color is not changing even by adding a css file and linking with html file?

Tags: css, html

I added a button code from bootstrap which goes like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Start Javascript
</button>
```

due to this code button color is red and i want to change that into orange for that i added a css file and linked that with html which goes like this:

```
.btn btn-danger {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

but still color of button is red insted of orange

Comment: `.btn.btn-danger { background-color: orange;}`

Comment: I works but why a extra dot?

Comment: `.btn btn-danger { background-color: orange !important;}` And make sure you css custom file load after boostrap.min.css file

Comment: @HT The dot is the css selector that selects for a given class. So `.btn.btn-danger` will select any element that has both the `btn` and `btn-danger` classes. You could probably make do with just selecting `.btn-danger`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct CSS rule is

```
.btn.btn-danger {
    background-color: orange;
}
```